# Element-wise multiplication in CVXPY

Tags: python, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I am trying to do element-wise multiplication in CVXPY in the objective function. Is this allowed as part of a convex problem?

`X` is a n x 1 variable.
`V` is a n x n constant.

I want to do the equivalent of `np.multiply(X, V*X)`, which returns an n x 1 vector.

Comment: Please show an example of the code you have, and describe what you've tried so far. Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more detail on how to ask a good question to maximize your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think the function you're looking for is `cvx.multiply`

For example:

```
In [1]: import cvxpy as cvx

In [2]: n = 10

In [3]: X = cvx.Variable((n, 1))

In [4]: V = cvx.Variable((n, n))

In [5]: cvx.multiply(X, V*X)
Out[5]: Expression(UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, (10, 1))
```

In the [1.0 update notes](https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/c5682fa0f66bd98b57a052d32170e2c6fda57b73/doc/source/updates/index.rst), they mention that this function used to be called `mul_elemwise` (<1.0), which may have been the source of your confusion.